# Include GitHub flavored markdown in Maven site

Tags: java, maven, markdown

I have a project on GitHub with a decent documentation in its GitHub wiki. For each release I'd like to take the current wiki and bake it into the generated Maven site. This would allow easy access to documentation that is accurate for that particular version.

The problem is, although Maven site supports markdown, it doesn't handle GitHub flavored markdown very well. This requires a lot of work to clean up the GitHub version and make it work with the flavor of markdown supported by the Maven site plugin.

So the question is, is there a way of having Maven site handle GitHub flavored markdown?

Comment: Cause of GitHub markdown is *not* markdown i only see the way to improve the appropriate [markdown module](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia/doxia-modules/doxia-module-markdown/).